# Get FreeTDS working on Heroku Cedar Stack

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, freetds, cedar

I'm trying to deploy my Rails app to Heroku.

I'm using Postgres, but in my database.yml I've also added a définition to access a remote sql server.

In my Gemfile :

```
gem 'tiny_tds', '0.5.1'
```

In a model :

```
establish_connection :my_sqlserver
```

This is working great in development mode, but when I try to deploy to Heroku I've an error message :

```
[...]
   Installing tiny_tds (0.5.1) with native extensions
   Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
   /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
   checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... yes
   checking for sybfront.h... no
   -----
   freetds is missing.
   -----
   *** extconf.rb failed ***
   Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
   necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
   details.  You may need configuration options.
[...]
```

I've found a tutorial to get it working but it's a little bit complex solution :
https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds/issues/74

Any ideas to get it working?

Thanks a lot...

Answer (score 4):

i had same problem.

try install freetds-devel.
freetds-devel is included by rpmforge yum repository.

Comment: How did you install freetds on heroku?